# Passing a function with templated parameters as an argument, with function pointers vs. std::function

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

So I have some generic class with two functions that take functions as parameters. One takes a function pointer and one takes a std::function. Both have a template parameter.

```
#include <functional>
#include <memory>

namespace {
    void example(const std::shared_ptr<const int>&) {}
}

class Generic {
public:
    Generic() {}
    virtual ~Generic() {}
    template <typename Targ>
    void doWork(std::function<void(const std::shared_ptr<const Targ>&)> arg) {}

    template <typename Targ>
    void doWork2(void(*function)(const std::shared_ptr<const Targ>&)) {}
};

class Special : public Generic {
public:
    Special() {
        //doWork(&example);   // Fail!
        doWork<int>(&example);  // OK!
        std::function<void(const std::shared_ptr<const int>&)> func = &example;
        doWork(func); // OK!
        doWork2(&example);  // OK!
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Special special;
    return 0;
}
```

With the function pointer it compiles, but with the std::function it does not. Why does template deduction fail here?

Clang reports:

```
example.cpp:27:9: error: no matching member function for call to 'doWork'
        doWork(&example);
        ^~~~~~
example.cpp:14:10: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'function<void (const shared_ptr<const type-parameter-0-0> &)>' against 'void (*)(const std::shared_ptr<const int> &)'
    void doWork(std::function<void(const std::shared_ptr<const Targ>&)> arg) {
         ^
1 error generated.
```

Comment: `example` is not a `std::function`, and potentially, several `std::function` could be construct from this function.

Comment: @Jarod42 but `&example` is a function pointer, and I can pass a function pointer as a `std::function`, no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Template argument deduction does not work like that.

Template argument deduction is a pattern match.  Is `example` an object of type `std::function<void(const std::shared_ptr<const Targ>&)>` for some type `Targ`?

Not convertible-to, but actually an object of that type already?

No, it is not.

It is, however, already a function pointer (using the implicit decay rules).

There is a C++17 feature that involve deducing template arguments from constructor types; `std::function` may or may not be instrumented to learn its own type from a function pointer when C++17 or C++20 comes out in this situation.  I lack expertise in C++17 to be certain.

Comment: _I lack expertise in C++17 to be certain_. I'd like to lack expertise as you do. :-)

Answer (score 2):

This happens because the constructor can't deduce the type of its class. If my wording sounds weird, perhaps this example will help:

```
template <class T>
class Example {
    Example(const T&) { /*...*/  }
};
```

If I have a function template, such as `template <class T> void f(const Example<T>&)`, I can't just do `f(10)`. This is what your code boils down to. `std::function` can't know its template parameters based on what you passed to its (non-explicit) constructor.

Note: this is, by the way, in the works for C++17.